# How to get the signed_request via the Facebook c# SDK

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

I've created an app that I'm going to be using as an iframe app for a tab inside my company's facebook page. On my side of things I've got a MVC 2 web app. I have two Views one that I want to display if the user already likes the page, and another when they don't. I've been looking at this entry which pretty much describes my issue.

[Read OAuth2.0 Signed_Request Facebook Registration C# MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575932/read-oauth2-0-signed-request-facebook-registration-c-mvc)

In the signed_request there is a page property which contains a boolean names liked which is the item I need to check. In the answer Nathan says you can use the SDK to not have to do it 'manually'. My question is how. I've got the SDK and I'm trying in ernest to figure out how to get the data I need out and also whether I need to decorate my Actions with any attributes?

Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CanvasContext object like this:

```
dynamic data = CanvasContext.Current.SignedRequest.Data
if (data.page.liked) {
 // has liked
} else {
 // Not liked
}
```

Comment: Do I need to import another namespace (other than Facebook, Facebook.Web & Facebook.Web.Mvc) or decorate the method with an attribute? I'm getting a CanvasContext does not exist in the current context build error and it's not recognising it in Visual Studio. :s