# Using Facebook's DeAuth Callback with the C# SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to handle the DeAuth callback from Facebook in my .Net MVC3, so that I can retrieve the UserId and remove the user from my database.

I've created an action that writes to a log file (for debugging purposes) using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433252/how-to-decode-oauth-2-0-for-canvas-signed-request-in-c/3747672#3747672):

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
string accessToken = app.Session.AccessToken;
long userId = app.UserId;
```

At first my code failed with `app` being `null`. I then tried to add the `CanvasAuthorizeAttribute` to the `Controller`, which didn't help much either. Is there some other attribute I should have added instead? Or is there something else I'm wrong?

**Edit:**

I'm using version 4.2.1 of the SDK.

**Edit 2:**
Thanks to [Pat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783541/using-facebooks-deauth-callback-with-the-c-sdk/4789991#4789991) I figured out that the following code does the job (without any attributes on the action or controller).

```
var app = new FacebookApp();
var userId = app.SignedRequest.UserId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this by parsing the signed_request that comes when Facebook hits your DeAuth page:

```
string signedRequestValue = Request.Form["signed_request"];
var app = new FacebookApp();
var sig = app.ParseSignedRequest(signedRequestValue);
long userid = sig.UserId;
```

I am using a prior release of the SDK that I had to modify to make the ParseSignedRequest public (it was private), but I believe this is a public method in the latest release 4.2.1 that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for setting me on the right path :). The code was actually even simpler than what you suggested.