# facebook registration plugin with working solution

Tags: facebook, registration, facebook-c#-sdk

Can somebody show me a working code example of facebook registration plugin in asp.net? I need to fetch the data from the url.

I dont want to use any 3rd party dll's and toolkit. Isn't there a simpler way of doing this..? really frustrated now.I simply want to get data from the registration plugin.

There are tons of question over here without any answer...please don't redirect me to some other pages. If you know the answer please post it here..

I am using the iframe example as shown on the developers.facebook.com website.

I need an asp.net c# sample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you check out [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). They hav given step by step as to how to have a registration plugin.

Comment: 1) Your link is incorrect..2)I have read these docs but couldnt find a way to parse the signed request to get the JSON string...3) I would request everybody to please write an answer here rather than sending me to different pages... There is not a single answer on stackoverflow showing how to solve this issue.. every question seems to be filled with answers pointing the user to different links..

Answer (score 0):

Here is some c# code to decode the `signed_request`.

[How to decode OAuth 2.0 for Canvas signed_request in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433252/how-to-decode-oauth-2-0-for-canvas-signed-request-in-c)

If the code works for you, can you send me a pull request and I'll put it in my example set?

https://github.com/ptarjan/signed-request