# Fans-only content in facebook with asp.net C# sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi i'm developing an application in facebook with c# sdk and i want that the user whom liked my page can only use my application. (Like [woobox](http://woobox.com/))

I found some solutions in php in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) but there isn't any source about .net how can i get the liked info in ASP.NET

I find another examples in php in [this](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-detect-fan-of-a-facebook-page/) link again but i can't find c# answer :\

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why the existing answer isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: Because it needs permissions, i need a code without getting permission like woobox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get signed request when your web page is loaded within facebook canvas app; you should be able to parse signed request something similar to following:

```
if (Request.Params["signed_request"] != null)
{
    string payload = Request.Params["signed_request"].Split('.')[1];
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
    var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
    var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
    var o = JObject.Parse(json);
    var lPid = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.id")).Replace("\"", "");
    var lLiked = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.liked")).Replace("\"", "");
    var lUserId= Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("user_id")).Replace("\"", "");
}
```

You need to add reference to json libraries in order to parse signed requestin C#, download from http://json.codeplex.com/

Also refere to [How to decode OAuth 2.0 for Canvas signed_request in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433252/how-to-decode-oauth-2-0-for-canvas-signed-request-in-c) if you are worndering about signed request.

Answer (score 4):

This is only possible with the legacy APIs, or with the [`user_likes` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). As you want a solution without specific permissions I'll show you 2 methods. Use them in combination with AJAX to refresh the page when a user presses `like`.

Option 1) REST API

Using the legacy API, it's possible to use [Pages.IsFan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan)

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/pages.isFan?
page_id=...&
uid=...&
access_token=...
```

Do this in C# as follows.

```
var appID = "....";
var appSecret = "....";
var uid = "....";
var pageId = "....";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
var appAuthUri = string.Concat("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?",
                            "client_id=", appID,
                            "&client_secret=", appSecret,
                            "&grant_type=", "client_credentials"
                            );
var response = client.DownloadString(appAuthUri);
var access_token = response.Split('=')[1];

var isFanUri = string.Concat("https://api.facebook.com/method/pages.isFan?",
                            "format=", "json",
                            "&page_id=", pageId,
                            "&uid=", uid,
                            "&access_token=", access_token
                            );
response = client.DownloadString(isFanUri);
bool isFan;
bool.TryParse(response, out isFan);
```

Option 2) Client side

The `FBXML` method. This is done with Javascript on the client, by subscribing to an event when the user clicks the `like` button. It's documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

> **How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?**
>
> If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to
>   the 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe.

Generate an FBXML like button [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=132240610207590&xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.thecodeking.co.uk" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Then subscribe to the `edge.create` event using the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Place this code in the document `BODY` preferably just before the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '245693305442004', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function (href, widget) {
                // Do something here
                alert('User just liked '+href);

            });
            (function () {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            } ());
    };
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @TheCodeKing i will try the option 2 but can you tell me how can you get uid in option1? Because in this case user didn't give permission to give any info to us and without uid i can't get Page.IsFan ?

Comment: Hi again i tried option 2 but it works when user likes or dislikes a page but i couldn't get that if the user liked the page before :\ do you have any opinion? thanks.

Comment: I think you get the uid if you add a login button so users are logged into your page. Theres a function FB.getUserId.

Comment: In Canvas application i can't have a facebook login button (It's not logical because user already logged in to facebook) so i can't get user's id?

Comment: If user is already logged in, I would have thought you can just call Fb.GetUserID() on the client. Does this not work?

Comment: Apparently if you call the IsFan API without a UID it will infer the currently logged in user, obviously this requires a client-side call.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.canvasAuthorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer {
    Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "publish_stream", "offline_access", "user_likes", "friends_about_me" }
};

this.canvasAuthorizer.Authorize();

if (FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized())
{
    this.facebookWebClient = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current);

    string requested_Data = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["signed_request"];
    dynamic decodedSignedRequest = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(this.facebookApplication, requested_Data);

    if (decodedSignedRequest.Data.page != null)
    {
        // Funs Page
        this.IsLike = decodedSignedRequest.Data.page.liked;
    }
    else
    {
        // Application Page
        dynamic likes = this.facebookWebClient.Get("/me/likes");
        foreach (dynamic like in likes.data)
        {
            if (like.id == this.FacebookFanPageID)
            {
                this.IsLike = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a canvas app, you could (should?) use the [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter to check if the user likes the page it's on:

```
# pseudocode
signed_request = decode_signed_request()
if signed_request['page']['liked']:
  # user liked page, do something cool
else:
  # user doesn't like page. redirect somewhere to tell them why they should
```

The `signed_request` is passed to your page as a POST variable; just as if there was a form field named `signed_request` and the form was submitted on the page previous to yours (in fact this is basically how facebook "runs" your app; the form is auto-submitted instead of waiting for a user to submit it). So in ASP.net you should be able to get it through the `Request` object:

```
Request["signed_request"]
```

This approach is useful if you're creating a "tab app" for a page; you can detect whether the user liked the page without them granting you extra permissions.

Comment: Hi @chesles can you give me some information about decode_signed_request()?

Comment: Check out the "verify and decode" heading in the [signed_request docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) for an outline on how to implement this. There are 2 parts, a signature and a payload. The payload is just [base64 encoded](http://base64decode.org/), so you will have to find out how to decode it in C#; I'm not a .Net guy but I'm sure there's a decoder library in there someplace.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in PHP with the help of an SQL Query

```
`$result = $facebook->api(array(  "method"    => "fql.query",
                                  "query"     => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=$uid AND page_id=$page_id"
                               ));
```

Here $result variable can be used for segregating the Fan and non-Fan content

Comment: Same problem i couldn't get uid without getting permission so it won't works :\

Comment: See without creating a FB session you cannot access any detail inside an application .. So first step will always be asking 4 basic set of permissions ( as required by your app ). then in the following steps you can decide based on the uid whether that person likes your page or not ..