# Facebook Like button click event on welcome page should open popup window of page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to capture Like button click event in facebook page in my facebook.

```
http://www.facebook.com/wineselectors
```

If anyone click on like button, it should open a popup window of page tab `http://www.facebook.com/wineselectors?sk=app_190348341034091`

I have used to below code to capture like click, but it  is not working.

```
<html> <script type="text/javascript"> 
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
          alert('the user likes a page');
    });

</script> <body> <center> <img src="http://www.wineselectors.com.au/images/UserUploadedImages/facebook-like--image.jpg" /> </center> </body> </html>
```

---

I am trying to develop an aspx page for welcome tab but how can I get signed_request in my aspx page and how to decode the signed_request. I have read some of the articles they were using Jason but i could not able to use Jason in my system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fans-only content in facebook with asp.net C# sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595259/fans-only-content-in-facebook-with-asp-net-c-sharp-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

When someone likes your page, the page gets completely refreshed and you would need to decode and inspect the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/) HTTP POST parameter in server code (not javascript) to see if they like your page. Then from there you could redirect the user as necessary.