# Facebook: Custom Landing Page "For Fans"

Tags: facebook

Facebook provides us with an option to choose a custom landing tab for the new visitors (i.e. non-fans). Can we have a custom Landing tab for fans so that every time i open the page, i m directed to that custom page rather than the Wall..

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595259/fans-only-content-in-facebook-with-asp-net-c-sdk) you can find the solution. I have asked the same question before and gave bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Facebook Help Center](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=205237756182353&ref_query=default)?

> **How can I select a tab as default for people who already Like my Page?**
>
> This functionality does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is straightforwrd.

1. Create a "landing page" tab app and add it to your page. Here is a  tutorial on how to do it: http://how-to-create-facebook-app.koliber.com
2. Make this tab the default for your app. On your page, in the upper-right corner click "Edit Page" and change the "Default Landing Tab" to the one you would like displayed by default.
3. Now everyone will be shown the default tab when they log in. How to distinguish between those visitors who "liked" your page and those that didn't? Easy. Make two versions of the page and display one to those who liked and one to those who didn't like. How to find out whether the current visitor liked your page or not follows:
4. When your Page Tab URL is called in the iframe, it is passed a signed_request POST parameter. This parameter contains the info you need. However, it is encoded and structured so it needs some processing to get the info
5. Split the signed_request on the '.' character. The first part is the signature. The second part is the encoded_data
6. Decode the encoded_data into a JSON string using the URLBase64Decode function equivalent in your server-side programming language
7. The JSON object contains a node called "page". This contains a node called "liked".
8. If "liked" is true, the user liked the page and you display the "liked" version of your app. If false, show the "Please like me" version of the site.

This way, when visitors visit your page, they see your custom app in a tab. The actual content is determined server-side on your server based on the page.liked property inside of the JSON object passed to you in signed_request

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer as far as I have been able to find out is "No". There is no setting which aligns with this requirement.

The wall is the default tab for people who like the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/ this application gives you those options... enjoy!