# Decode Signed Request Without Authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Are we able to use the Facebook C# SDK to decode the **signed_request** parameter that is passed to the Facebook Tab page, **without using Authentication**? Basically, I am looking for a way to decode and parse the **page JSON object** that the signed_request contains.

I am looking for the **.NET C#** equivelent to accomplishing the same type of decode in this PHP example: [Seamless way to check if user likes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am just pasting same answer I have answered in another post.

[Fans-only content in facebook with asp.net C# sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595259/fans-only-content-in-facebook-with-asp-net-c-sharp-sdk)

You get signed request when your web page is loaded within facebook canvas app; you should be able to parse signed request something similar to following:

```
if (Request.Params["signed_request"] != null)
{
    string payload = Request.Params["signed_request"].Split('.')[1];
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
    var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
    var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
    var o = JObject.Parse(json);
    var lPid = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.id")).Replace("\"", "");
    var lLiked = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.liked")).Replace("\"", "");
    var lUserId= Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("user_id")).Replace("\"", "");
}
```

You need to add reference to json libraries in order to parse signed requestin C#, download from http://json.codeplex.com/

Also refere to [How to decode OAuth 2.0 for Canvas signed_request in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433252/how-to-decode-oauth-2-0-for-canvas-signed-request-in-c) if you are worndering about signed request.

Comment: Thanks this method worked well for decoding and parsing the Facebook signed_request with JSON!

Comment: I just tried it and while liked status and page id are working, for some reason lUserId cannot be parsed. any ideas why?

Comment: @mathew you have to make sure that you are logged in to facebook, when you are on company page.

Comment: @Imran yes i am sure i was logged in.Anyway i parsed UserId via javascript api. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'without authentication'? The signed request is signed with your app secret, so you can decode it regardless of whether the current user has authorised your app

{edit} I now realise you're referring to a library named Authentication{/edit}

If you find another library or reimplement the algorithm for HMAC SHA-256 and a base64url decoder i'm sure you could do it without using that specific library, but it's probably easier to just use it