# need retrieving userid from facebook c# sdk without making a request to facebook for it

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, userid

I need to get an easy facebook userid without having to do a request to facebook.

I am at a loss. I have been using the 'FBConnectAuth.dll' se easily for all my facebooking in my web application but since last week it does not work no more.

So I switched (or tried to) to this new c# sdk version 5.4. After 2 days I finally found enough documentation online to figure the basic and be able to make requests to facebook for user information with this method:

```
Dim fb = New FacebookWebClient()
FBUser = DirectCast(fb.[Get]("me"), IDictionary(Of String, Object))
```

Fine... so I can do a request to facebook...

But why can't I find a way to get the userID without calling this method and making a special request to facebook?

Without that UserID there is no way to cache the user data retrieved from the facebook request so this means a request to facebook on each page view.

Answer (score 0):

For a logged in user you can find the user id using:

```
Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.Current.UserId
```

This reads the userid from the authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

User id is part of Signed request which is part of your application. so as soon as you load your web page inside facebook app you are able to access signed request and hence user id.

You can also parse signed request by using Json, see my answer in this post you will get more idea about it.
[Decode Signed Request Without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891303/decode-signed-request-without-authentication/7938346#7938346)