# facebook c# sdk page tab application

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, tabs

First of all, sorry for my newbie question...
I am google-ing for something like that for days, but still no luck.

I can't find any examples for **using the Facebook C# SDK 
with Facebook Page Tab applications**.
Unfortunately most examples are for Facebook Canvas applications 
and I can't make them work with a Page Tab application.

I really need to see a working example of the following:

1. Get whether the User Liked my page, or not.
2. If the User Liked my page, show an "authorize" link/button.
3. On clicking the "authorize" link/button, ask for User's permission to:
    access his info, post to his wall, etc. 
   (using facebook's usual dialogs for that)
4. After the User accepts, redirect him to the "member's only" page. 
   (...inside the tab application frame. not a canvas-type frame)
5. Whenever an "authorized" User comes back to my tab app, 
   he should be automaticaly redirected to the same "member's only" page.
   (I suppose if I have an example for the previous steps, 
   I won't have a problem figuring this out)

Answer (score 1):

Building app for canvas is the same as making it for Page tab. The only difference is the so called "fangate" (liker/non-likers). 
This can be used out of the box only on page tabs and the only thing you need is to decode the signed request passed by facebook.

There is good explanation for doing this with C# here:

[Decode Signed Request Without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891303/decode-signed-request-without-authentication)

Comment: many thanks for your help!  I will try it the soonest and I will update

Comment: Finally I managed to make this work with Facebook Graph Toolkit!    [link](http://fgt.codeplex.com)