# Referral Url's on Facebook Page tab

Tags: c#, facebook, signed

I have a Facebook Page Tab app and I'm trying to find out where visitors to the page tab are coming from.  I've read on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ that you can get these from app_data in the signed request but whenever I try getting the signed request app_data isn't there.

I used FB.getLoginStatus to get the signed request when inside the tab on Facebook, but
When I debug the signed request with http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo I get the error "Bad Signature"

Your signed_request was probably not signed with our app_id of xxxxx  Here is the payload:
{
   "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
   "code": "xxxx",
   "issued_at": xxxx,
   "user_id": "xxxx2"
}

I'm using the C# SDK with Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the signed request with the code in this topic:
[Decode Signed Request Without Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891303/decode-signed-request-without-authentication)

```
if (Request.Params["signed_request"] != null)
{
    string payload = Request.Params["signed_request"].Split('.')[1];
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
    var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
    var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
    var o = JObject.Parse(json);
    var lPid = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.id")).Replace("\"", "");
    var lLiked = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("page.liked")).Replace("\"", "");
    var lUserId= Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("user_id")).Replace("\"", "");
}
```

It should be easy to get the app_data by adding

```
var lAppData = Convert.ToString(o.SelectToken("app_data")).Replace("\"", "");
```

To the have the app_data for your tab app you need to add it to the redirect url when acquiring permissions. You redirect url should something like:

http://facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID&app_data=add,whatever,parameters,you,want,here

I can only guess that the reason you got this error is because you just pasted your signed request in the address bar instead of the one used by the echo tool. The error is because your signed request is signed by your app_id and you're trying to use it with echo which has another app_id. But that's just a guess :)

My primary language is PHP but hope I was able to help :)

Comment: The value of O is {
  "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
  "expires": 1331035200,
  "issued_at": 1331029487,
  "oauth_token": "xxxxx",
  "page": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "liked": false,
    "admin": true
  },
  "user": {
    "country": "gb",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "age": {
      "min": 21
    }
  },
  "user_id": "xxxx"
}
but as you can see still no app_data

Comment: have you added app_data to the redirect url? The whole idea of app data is to have it on these redirects. If possible, please provide the code where you construct your login url.

Comment: As I understood it app_data is encoded into the signed request.  The signed request is retrieved using  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    window.location.href = "/?signed_request=" + window.response.authResponse.signedRequest;
                } else {
                    // no user session available, someone you dont know
                }
            });  

the the home controller deals with the request.

Comment: yes, it is encoded in signed_request. But the signed request is encoded by facebook on the log in page. If you want it to include any data in app_data you need to send that data to facebook login screen. 
For reference I'm giving you the auth link of one of my apps.
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=372739966077200&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fpages%2FMyPage%2F11111111111%3Fsk%3Dapp_1111111111111%26app_data%3Dadmin_gate&scope=
See how app_data is added.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I don't have access to the Referral URL from Facebook and my understanding is that app_data is something that is sent over by Facebook much like the page and user data, rather than something I can attach.  Are there any tutorials or links you followed that I could try out?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/
Read here for app_data, the reason I tell you to add it to redirect_uri is so that after your app is authorized in the address bas you will see:
http://www.facebook.com/MollySimsOfficial?v=app_135607783795&app_data=any_string_here

Comment: I think I see what you mean, so the only way to see the url paramaters is if the paramater is called app_data?  so it's not possible to access something like ?ref=MyRef?

Comment: Specifically I want to find out where people are coming to our page from, and we won't be able to get the internet to add ?app_data=stuff to their URL's.  so what I want to know is if there's a way around this

Comment: Have you thought about Request.UrlReferrer?