# Check if user liked page or not

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have read a lot of related topics here regarding this problem but I am still not able to do something like this

http://www.facebook.com/Dominos/app_252492331452398

Below is the code i am using

here are my questions.

- So I am already logged in into my facebook page
- If I go to the above dominos url, i can like or unlike the page. The dominos content changes based on whether I have liked or unlike the page. But they are not asking we to log in again
- In my code below although I already logged in my facebook. i don't get access to my userinfo until I click login button and login in again in the provided popup. how can I skip this step as the dominos is doing. I am getting response.status as not_authorized

  - I know once I log in, I can do something like to check whether the user has liked my page or not

  var query = FB.Data.query( 'select page_id from page_fan where uid='+response.authResponse.userID+' and page_id ='+PAGE_ID);

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fbjquery</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<h2>Updated JS SDK example</h2><br />
<div id="user-info"></div>
<p><button id="fb-auth">Login</button></p>


<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: 'App_ID', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
        console.log("inside update button "+response.authResponse);
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(response.authResponse);
      //user is already logged in and connected
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
      + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
      });
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML="";
    });
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      button.innerHTML = 'Login';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML = 
                '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' 
            + response.id + '/picture" style="margin-right:5px"/>' 
            + response.name;
        });    
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:'email'});    
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes

  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    


};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related/dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a programmatic way as well, not necessarily just in the context of a tab.

Note that it will require you to ask for the "user_likes" permission from the user in your O-Auth connect dialog.

This code snippet will test for whether someone currently likes something or not:

```
    FB.api('/me/likes/MY_PAGE_ID', {limit: 1}, function(r) { 
        if (r.data.length == 1) {
            //do stuff when the user is a liker
        } else {
            //do stuff when the user is not currently a liker           
        }
    });
```

If you want to catch the event when the user clicks the like button, then you can use FB.Event.subscribe:

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
         function(response) {
              //Do stuff when the user just clicked a "like" button
         }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

On a Facebook fan page, when the user clicks the Like button, the whole page gets reloaded and Facebook sends an HTTP post to your website with a parameter called signed_request that you would need to decode and look at with server code. *Signed Request* is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). Once decoded, you will need to look at the **page.liked** value.

Might be helpful:

[Fans-only content in facebook with asp.net C# sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595259/fans-only-content-in-facebook-with-asp-net-c-sharp-sdk)

Comment: thanks for you reply but how do i do this "In my code below although I already logged in my facebook. i don't get access to my userinfo until I click login button and login in again in the provided popup. how can I skip this step as the dominos is doing"