# How do I make Facebook like-detection work on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I have built a simple webpage in PHP.  I want to tell if users like my page (I placed a like button on it).  It is not a Facebook app.  I have seen [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), but don't know how to use it with PHP.  I don't know JavaScript at all.  I tried pasting the code listed at the link into my page, but it didn't do anything useful.

A PHP solution would be preferable.  I don't want to build a Facebook app, I just want to know if the Like button has been pressed.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:  Here's the link to my website, per answerer request:  [testingground.comyr.com](http://testingground.comyr.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those Edge events are only usable to detect if the user clicked the Like Button right now, but you cannot check if he already liked your page. That is only possible with an App, and user authorization with the "user_likes" permission.

More information:

- [Check if logged in user has liked my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042350/check-if-logged-in-user-has-liked-my-facebook-page)
- [Check if user liked page or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850285/check-if-user-liked-page-or-not)

Comment: So I guess the answer is, "I can't."

Comment: without an app and user authorization, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [Facebook developer reference documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)? 
Without an API Access, I think there is no possibility to do that.
How should you have access the private token what a random user liked?