# User Likes a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way to see if a facebook user liked a page? 
It might not be the logged in user, a user might not be logged in at all... The page might not be the page where the app is installed.
Thanks!

Comment: did you try this https://graph.facebook.com/<pageid>/likes

Comment: Yes, that returns the likes that a page have? I also tried https://graph.facebook.com/UID/likes/PAGEID?access_token=XXX - this seems to work, but only for my account. When I tried with other random accounts, the response is FALSE. Maybe I am setup as developer? :(

Comment: why you not using only your account to check likes? you can get all likes in json and then compare with uid wheather user exist or not

Comment: It's the same, I tried to get https://graph.facebook.com/MYID/likes?access_token=XXX - it works, i get all pages I liked, no matter if I'm logged in or not. But for another user, it doesn't work :(

Comment: This is the thing: A user, A page... they might not be related, owner... user might not be logged in... As I seen, for the graph/UID/likes/PAGEID - user has to grant the user_likes permission to the app...

Comment: yes, then you need user_likes permission to access his likes

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you have the "user_likes" scope. Then you use the graph api by doing a ('me/likes'), and put a condition on it (if name=='yourpage').

Answer (score 0):

You can get user likes with permissions in application or if your application is a canvas application you can get it with this way;

[Fans-only content in facebook with asp.net C# sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595259/fans-only-content-in-facebook-with-asp-net-c-sharp-sdk)

Comment: Yes, but use has to give permissions to the application, right?

Comment: if canvas application user don't have to give permission you can get it with the link i gave before