# Customizing a facebook app

Tags: asp.net, facebook, iframe-app

Is it possible to create a Facebook tab application which a user can install to their page, which allows the passing of a customization value.

It *is* possible to create a link which will load the application on the user's page, and pass an app_data value to your app:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

> In addition, your application will also receive a string parameter called app_data as part of signed_request if an app_data parameter was set in the original query string in the URL your tab is loaded on. For the Shop Now link above, that could look like this: "http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here". You can use that to customize the content you render if you control the generation of the link.

But is it possible to distribute a personalized link (i.e. including an id=xyz query-string parameter) to an app which, when installed, adds an app tab to the users page,and  will include this personalization value in the app_data (either in the GET or POST data), and thus enable the page to be personalized by parsing out the value (as illustrated here [Facebook webforms app get app_data querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625242/facebook-webforms-app-get-app-data-querystring))

Comment: oh no. the silence of the grave. I'm guessing that means I am dead here?

Comment: does this help? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCUF3zV9xj0

Comment: I will check it out and post back, thanks.

Comment: No, this simply outlines basic app creation and accessing the signed request to detect if the user liked the app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [application settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), you can set a "Page Tab Edit URL" :

> The URL to the Edit link displayed on your application's profile box.
>   An admin of a Facebook Page that has added your application can follow
>   the URL to edit the application settings for the Page.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/)

When your app is added to a page, and a visitor is coming, you'll get a [Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) (Posted to your app) containing the page ID, [more infos here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462).
You just have to store custom infos for each page ID you get.

Comment: Thanks Chris I'll check this out, and post back here

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDelsart this solution looks like it will work. It does require the page admin to go through the edit steps, but that is easily documented and should be ok