# How to use Facebook deauthorize callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am using ASP.NET
I would like to implement the listener for the FB de-auth.

I get signed_request param from the FB server.
How can I decrypt it using C#?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode OAuth 2.0 for Canvas signed_request in C#? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433252/how-to-decode-oauth-2-0-for-canvas-signed-request-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex, you could either use it or check out how they handle the signed_request encryption. There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385593/c-hmacsha256-problem-matching-facebook-signed-request-implementation) SO post which has a similar slant.

Not really an answer I admit, just don't know how to put links into comments

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you came right ... but I referenced the Facebook C# SDK and did this:

Deauth.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["signed_request"]))
    {

        string signed_request = Request["signed_request"];

        Dictionary<string, Facebook.JSONObject> jsonDict = new Dictionary<string, Facebook.JSONObject>();
        if (Helper.FacebookAPI.ValidateSignedRequest(signed_request, out jsonDict))
        {

            if (jsonDict.ContainsKey("user_id"))
            {
                long FacebookId = jsonDict["user_id"].Integer;
                // delete code
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then my Facebook Helper class looks like this:

```
namespace Helper {
public static class FacebookAPI
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Facebook.JSONObject> DecodePayload(string payload)
    {
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
        var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
        var jObject = Facebook.JSONObject.CreateFromString(json);            
        return jObject.Dictionary;
    }


    public static bool ValidateSignedRequest(string VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST, out Dictionary<string, Facebook.JSONObject> json)
    {
        string applicationSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"];
        string[] signedRequest = VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST.Split('.');
        string expectedSignature = signedRequest[0];
        string payload = signedRequest[1];

        json = DecodePayload(payload);

        // Attempt to get same hash
        var Hmac = SignWithHmac(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationSecret));
        var HmacBase64 = ToUrlBase64String(Hmac);

        return (HmacBase64 == expectedSignature);
    }


    private static string ToUrlBase64String(byte[] Input)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Input).Replace("=", String.Empty)
                                            .Replace('+', '-')
                                            .Replace('/', '_');
    }

    private static byte[] SignWithHmac(byte[] dataToSign, byte[] keyBody)
    {
        using (var hmacAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256(keyBody))
        {
            hmacAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataToSign);
            return hmacAlgorithm.Hash;
        }
    }


    public static string SerializeDict(Dictionary<string, Facebook.JSONObject> jsonDict)
    {
        // serialize the dictionary
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(jsonDict.GetType());

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                // add formatting so the XML is easy to read in the log
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                serializer.WriteObject(writer, jsonDict);

                writer.Flush();

                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }



    public static string GetAuthToken()
    {

        string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppId"];
        string secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"];

        string url = String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials", appId, secret);

        string[] token = HttpGetData(url).Split('=');
        return token[1];
    }

    public static string HttpGetData(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return (reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    public static string HttpPostData(string url, string nameValuePair)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url + "&" + nameValuePair) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                return (reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
}}
```